# How to choose a specific backend VM using Azure Application Gateway path based routing rule

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

In a web application deployed on several Azure VMs, load is balanced using Application Gateway. The selection of Application Gateway is mainly because the application requires cookie-based session affinity.

For a function in the application, a specific VM in the Backend Pool needs to be chosen. So I think giving the user a different login page URL could help me route things properly.

I've tried using different rules, but since a listener can have only one rule this doesn't work in my case.

What I want to achieve is:
https://myapplication/mycontext

- Balanced between all the VMs

While https://myapplication/mycontext/process

- Directed to a specific VM
- Path rewritten to https://myapplication/mycontext

What should the configuration of a Path-Based Rule be to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to create 2 backend pool, one to server all content (A) and one specific pool for /process requests (B).

Create a path based rule, a default rule to forward /mycontext/* to the backend pool A
another rule to forward /mycontext/process/* to another backend pool B.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure I'm doing things right, but I understand I would need a different listener if I'm to use two different rules and I need both of them to go to the same port, so I can't really create a different listener.

Comment: You need to create multi-site listener and specify the hostname if you are using the same port

Comment: But then I need to access the application through 2 different DNS names, don't I?

Comment: My bad, for the path based rule, you don't need to specify two different rules. In a single path based rule, you can define multiple the path, HTTP Settings and backend pool.

Comment: I see, that worked!!! I thought you needed to create a single "path-based" rule for each path and that's were I was going wrong. It was indeed very simple, just like you described it. Thank you!